# Which (GIS/CAD-) software to use for transformation of ~2k .dwg - files?

Tags: gis, cad

I've got approx 2000 .dwg-files that have to be transformed (GK to DB_REF) via custom transformation (I've got a list with coordinates in EPSG:31467 of ground control points and a specific angle of rotation). I've already tried to do this via FME (offsetter + affiner) and Global Mapper (batch convert/reproject), but in the resulting file, there are elements missing (primarily texts) or elements get changed (e.g. text sizes), which should remain untouched.

Do you know of any software that is more appropriate for this task and does not cause the mentioned problems?